# Firebase Serialization Issues [UPDATED]

Tags: java, android, firebase, serialization, firebase-realtime-database

I asked this question last night but I don't think I offered enough information, so I am going to try to be a lot more thorough!

I am trying to make it so that when a user registers for my app, their data along with some other variables will be saved in Firebase Realtime Database. I continue to get a serialization error when an account tries to register.

> No properties to serialize found on class com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zza$3

And I have tried countless things to fix the error but nothing really seems to be fixing it or making any progress towards fixing it. This is the registration method I am using currently.

```
       firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //start profile activity here

                User users = new User(username, email, wins, losses, balance);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(users)
                        .addOnCompleteListener
                                (new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, HomePage.class ));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressDialog.hide();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration not successful, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        }
    });
```

And specifically the error is being called on this part of the code

```
.setValue(users)
```

I have made sure all of my variables are public, and I have added getters and setters for everything as well (which I do not know if it is necessary).

My User class looks like this

```
    public User(String userName, String email, int wins, int losses, double balance) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.losses = losses;
        this.balance = balance;
}
```

And I also have proguard enabled, and I have added rules to -keep my User class and my RegisterActivity class. These are the rules I added in

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers com.example.brent.fifty_fifty.** {
  *;
}
-keep class com.example.brent.fifty_fifty.RegisterActivity
-keep class com.example.brent.fifty_fifty.User
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

I am not sure if I have my rules right, or if I have some unnecessary rules in there, but this is all a learning process so please let me know if anything looks wrong or you have a suggestion on how to fix the error!

Sorry for posting so frequently

My User.class

```
package com.example.brent.fifty_fifty;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
public class User {

public String userName, email, specUserName;
public int wins, losses;
public double balance;
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users/"+uid);

public User() {

}

public User(String userName, String email, int wins, int losses, double balance) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.email = email;
    this.wins = wins;
    this.losses = losses;
    this.balance = balance;
}

public interface MyCallback{
    void onSuccess(String userName);
}

public void getUserName(final MyCallback myCallback) {
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            specUserName = dataSnapshot.child("userName").getValue(String.class);
            myCallback.onSuccess(specUserName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            throw databaseError.toException();
        }
    });
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getWins() {
    return wins;
}

public void setWins(int wins) {
    this.wins = wins;
}

public int getLosses() {
    return losses;
}

public void setLosses(int losses) {
    this.losses = losses;
}

public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have added in your `User` class the `balance` object which is of type `BigDecimal`. As in the official documentation regarding [Firebase realtime databse data tyes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), the `BigDecimal` is not a supported data type. To solve this, you should change te type of your `balance` object to a supported data type. I recommend you to change it to a `Double`.

Comment: I changed the balance to a double type, and I even tried just getting rid of balance all together. But the error still arises. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I updated all the classes up in the original post. Do you want to see an entire class? Like the User class where balance double is defined or what?

Comment: Please share your entire User class.

Comment: Just added it to the bottom :)

Comment: I see now. Your User class must **not** define fields of any other type that are not supported.  Beeing a model class, you should **only** define the fields that are needed in your database, for instance: `userName`, `email`, `wins`, `losses` and `balance`, the constructors, the getters and setters if needed. Any other code should be moved to another class, let's say `UtilsClass` or `HelperClass`.  So you should remove everything that is related to `user`, `database` and `myRef` objects (declarations, methods etc).

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much I have been stuck on this for awhile!